Reverse proxy using IP but with TLS
I created a load balancer that looks up the IP addresses of the provided servers and then does a reverse proxy:
func loadBalancer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ip := getIP()

    proxy := httputil.ReverseProxy{
        Rewrite: func(proxyRequest *httputil.ProxyRequest) {
            proxyRequest.SetURL(&url.URL{
                Scheme: "https",
                Host:   ip.String(),
            })

            proxyRequest.Out.Host = proxyRequest.In.Host
        },
    }

    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

In theory it is working, but I'm having issues with the TLS certificate. Since the certificates are only issued to domains and not to IP addresses, the certificate verification is failing:
http: proxy error: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: cannot validate certificate for <IP> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

How can I fix that?

In hosts file of the reverse proxy, for ex. if three backend hosts exist, enter the internal FQDNs of the three backend hosts and their respective internal IP addresses. When you form the URL for the backend, this should be like https://host1.intra.app. This method requires X509 certificate with CN = www.app.net, SAN (subject alternate names) = host1.intra.app, host2.intra.app, host3.intra.app where www.app.net is the name of the app known by users.
If this new x509 certificate is provided by a known root CA , then additional cost may occur.
If you have an internal Certification Authority you may generate this certificate on this Certification Authority and distribute this certificate w/ private key to the reverse proxy (assuming first TLS decryption occurs at the reverse proxy) and to all backend hosts. The certificate of the internal Certificate Authority (CA certificate) should exist in the Trusted Root Store of every device that uses the application and all the application servers.

I'm sure that would work, but it's a complex solution requiring setup of /etc/hosts, internal DNS, etc.  There must be a more generic solution like curl's --resolve
